# from..import:Importing Python Modules

Tags: python-2.7

I am completely a newbie to Python programming. Modules have from..import statement. It allows us to store specific values. Hence, my doubt is that if it allows me to import specific attributes why am I still able to access other functions/variables of the same module in it without any error? Shouldn't the other attributes become inaccessible when not imported entirely?
For example,
Consider I have a module named `stuff.py` which has the following content

```
    def hello():
        print "Hello!! You are in module stuff !"
    a="Hello Again "
```

So when I do

```
    from stuff import hello

    hello()
    a=1
    print a
```

Shouldn't it give an error? Since, a should not be imported and hence cannot be used. (I am trying to relate this entire importing of modules as classes in C++ and Java, that if I am not importing anything in module it must be private and hence cannot be accessed.)

Comment: ...what? You're specifically assigning to `a`, otherwise (as you explicitly exclude it from import) you would get a `NameError`. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was expecting that when I do `a=1` or just `print a` (without changing `a`) , it gives me error something like cannot be accessed or value cannot be changed instead of changing it.

Comment: Why? Even if you *had* imported `a` Python has no problem with you shadowing it. The only things you can never assign to are [keywords](https://docs.python.org/2/library/keyword.html). The whole point about being specific about the names you're using from other modules is that you can then use other names without confusion, which is why `from foo import *` (wildcard import) is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

In your main, you have already defined another variable "a" with `a=1`
Therefore when you call "print a" you are calling the `"a"` variable in your main and not the `"a"` variable defined in your `stuff.py`

You should get the following output:

```
Hello!! You are in module stuff !
1
```

Comment: So Python is creating another variable `a` and printing it instead of printing `a` from `stuff.py`. Right?

Comment: @R_2293 that's not quite how Python names work - see e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks this helped and made the concept of assignments a lot more clearer but I might sound here repetitive, if I do `print stuff.a` should it not give error (because I am assuming it'll be out of scope when the module is imported partially) ?

Comment: @R_2293 that would only work if you `import stuff`, rather than `from stuff import <not a>`; in the latter case, the name `stuff` isn't in scope so you'll get a `NameError` unless it's assigned locally some other way.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks !!